# Is it possible to bridge/join two or more vritual (Hyper-V) switches with the same address range over VPN?

Tags: vpn, virtualization, hyper-v, switch

I have several Hyper-V servers which are not in the same LAN. On every server are several Hyper-V guest VMs which are connected via an internal virtual switch. Now I want to to connect these two virtual switches so that the guest VMs (and hosts) can connect to each other as if they would all be plugged in one real switch.

Example:

- Hyper-V Host A public IP (physical NIC): 123.123.123.1
- Hyper-V Host A IP on virutal switch (virtual NIC): 10.0.0.10/24
- Hyper-V Guest A1 IP: 10.0.0.20/24
- Hyper-V Guest A2 IP: 10.0.0.30/24
- Hyper-V Host B public IP (physical NIC): 123.123.123.2
- Hyper-V Host B IP on virutal switch (virtual NIC): 10.0.0.100/24
- Hyper-V Guest B1 IP: 10.0.0.110/24
- Hyper-V Guest B2 IP: 10.0.0.120/24

Currently A and B machines cannot communicate with each other but only with other A or other B machines. And I want to connect Host A and B over their public IPs in a way so that they will act like on the same LAN/switch and Guest B1 for example could reach 10.0.0.20. Is this possible and if so what is the easiest way?
 I know I could set up for example OpenVPN on every machine but I'd much prefer a solution which doesn't require any special setup on guest machines but only on Host A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a layer 2 bridge running over a layer 3 network. You can accomplish this a few of different ways. Here's a couple, off the top of my head:

- Microsoft's [Hyper-V Network Virtualization Gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134230.aspx) can do what you're looking for. It encapsulates layer 2 traffic for different virtual subnets between hosts in GRE.
- You could use a router with layer 2 tunneling functionality like GRE or L2TP. You could do this in software as a virtual router, or with a hardware router.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I read through Hyper-V network virtualization documentations as it seemed obvious to use that when I'm using Hyper-V anyways. However it felt quite overloaded for such a simple scenario like mine with just a few host servers and searching for layer 2 bridges I stumbled on SoftEther with which I was able to set up what I wanted in minutes (http://goo.gl/mhhsGO). And I have to say I'm quite impressed of SoftEther capabilities...